# Yandex Connect MX records for this domain have not been set up

Tags: mx-record, yandex

I've tried to move my domain from GoDaddy to Yandex Connect

And in the admin setting about my domain, I see:

> MX records for this domain have not been set up

But MX record added automatically

```
Host: @ 
Record type: MX
Record value: mx.yandex.net.
Priority: 10
```

And it's look like in [docs](https://yandex.com/support/domain/troubleshooting/domain-access.html)

I wrote a mail to support, but wait for an answer too long

Comment: You need to wait some time (2-3 days) until Yandex will retrieve new records. If it will not happen after some time, write to Yandex.Connect support.

Answer (score 4):

3 months have passed and I've got a letter from Yandex about this. Maybe it can help to somebody :)

> Hello, Igor!
>
> We apologize for such a long wait for a response! For technical
>   reasons, your message came to us just now.
>
> Your domain is currently not configured with the MX record required
>   for mail operation: https://yandex.ru/support/connect/dns/mx.html. It
>   must be configured on the servers to which your domain is delegated:
>
> **Name Server: NS77.DOMAINCONTROL.COM**
>
> **Name Server: NS78.DOMAINCONTROL.COM**
>
> Please add a MX record with **priority** 10 and value **mx.yandex.net**. (the
>   dot at the end of the server name is required if your control panel
>   does not add it by default).
>
> After the necessary settings have been made, and the information has
>   time to update (this can take up to 72 hours), you can check the
>   operation of the mail.

*I don't have already this problem because I've return my domain back to GoDaddy and don't have needs in domain for mail. If this helps to You let me know. I'll sign this answer as correct*

Comment: Yep, the dot was my problem (the dot at the end of the server name is required if your control panel does not add it by default)

Answer (score 1):

I got the same error message, while a difference for me is that I added the MX records to my current GoDaddy domain according to their [guide](https://yandex.com/support/connect/dns/mx.html).

With third party tools, I can find my MX record has been propagated correctly, but I still get the error saying "MX records for this domain have not been set up".

Not sure how long Yandex takes to refresh my MX records status. Let me wait for couple hours, will post an update if it goes through.

Comment: I waited for over 1 day, while it's still saying "MX records for this domain have not been set up". Then I moved my domain from GoDaddy to Yandex, i.e. change the DNS server of my domain to dns1.yandex.net and dns2.yandex.net, and waited another 2 days, the message remains. But it doesn't block sending and receiving emails, I also added another emails accounts of my domain, it works perfectly. From the Yandex DNS Management panel, we can also see the SPF record and DKIM record are generated automatically, so everything seems fine to me, except for the warning message.